# Mouse position and offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I get mouse coordinates on some web page and save them.

```
$("div#container").mousemove( function(e) {
      client_x = e.pageX;
  client_y = e.pageY;

  // save x,y

});
```

Now other person load that same page and i want to show them the same coordinates (x,x position).

How can I get the same point if I have to take in consideration that the div#container is not at same position as it was in my browser (considering screen resolution and scroll)?

Comment: Same point relative to #container or browser window?

Comment: I think is better relative to container, because container can move left, right if screens resolution change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible because of the variables you mentioned in the question. Screen resolution is the main reason, but, also, it depends on how big their window is. At first, you might think that you could compute the mouse's position relative to fixed points, like `div`s shown (take Stack Overflow, for example, where the main container of the site doesn't resize with the browser window). But if their window is smaller than the container, you would be making some false assumptions about what they see.

That being said, you can always just compute the mouse position relative to fixed elements you know will be on the screenusing `$.offset()` and just assume they have their screen showing everything (or check `$(window)` size) and are using "normal" viewing conditions.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `$.offset().top` and `$.offset().left` of the parent div container, and calculate the difference from that to the current X and Y coordinates of the mouse cursor.

`.offset()` always refers to the document and not to the parent of the element.

For example:

```
$('#element').mousemove(function(e){
    var client_x = e.pageX;
    var client_y = e.pageY;
    var elementOffset = $(this).offset();
    client_x -= elementOffset.left;
    client_y -= elementOffset.top;

    // save x, y.
});
```

Then, on the other users display, show the coordinates after adding them to his offsets.

Comment: Good answer but it would be better if you'd provide cleaner code by caching variables. So only do $(this) once and only do $.offset() once. (and you can leave out the -= altogether)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I appreciate the attention to detail and changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values returned by `offset()`, in your example:

`$("div#container").offset().left`
and
`$("div#container").offset().top`

to substract them to `e.pageX`and `e.pageY`.

`offset()` function gives you the matched element's position relative to the document (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)), so there's no problem if the users scroll down.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3jMRS/